# Email sent from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, email, parse-platform

In my app, a user can send an email from the app clicking on a button.

The needed function receives the email recipient from a parse.com object.

The first time the function is called, the app throws an error: is not a valid email address.

I have put `print("Email=",self.emailConsulta)`  to check if the received email address is valid or not, and it is valid.

Then I close the email and if I click on the send email button again, then it works fine and the email app from the device shows the received email address as recipient for the email.

Here is the code, I haven't found the issue there, any help is welcome:

```
@IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "datos_contacto")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("G5w8G3kVBG", block: {
        (questionObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let direccion: AnyObject! = questionObject!.objectForKey("dato_contacto")

        self.emailConsulta  = direccion as! String

        print("Email=",self.emailConsulta)


    })

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property


    print (emailConsulta)

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([emailConsulta])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Enviado desde Pedro Villarejo App Clientes (iOs)...")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Escriba aqui su texto", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}
func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: @Anas It is a message in the console: is not a valid email address. And the recipient field is empty..then on the second launch, everything works fine

Comment: You are fetching the email address from parse in the background. My guess is that the first time this query hasn't completed before you display the compose controller

Comment: @Paulw11 is right. It's clearly an issue about an asynchronous call.

Comment: @Paulw11, I guess you are right, let me check the app making the call earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting the destination mail address from Parse in the background, so in some cases your function will return before the data has been retrieved from Parse.  You can restructure your code so that the mail compose controller is presented from the completion closure -

```
@IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.showMailComposeController()
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func showMailComposeController() {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "datos_contacto")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("G5w8G3kVBG", block: {
        (questionObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let direccion: AnyObject! = questionObject!.objectForKey("dato_contacto")

        self.emailConsulta  = direccion as! String

        print("Email=",self.emailConsulta)

        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([emailConsulta])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Enviado desde Pedro Villarejo App Clientes (iOs)...")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Escriba aqui su texto", isHTML: false)
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 

    })

}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```